# Upload Django static files to S3 (Frankfurt) with boto

Tags: django, amazon-s3, boto3

I've added `os.environ['S3_USE_SIGV4'] = 'True'` to my boto config, because the S3's Frankfurt region only supports this type. Currently I receive the following error: `boto.s3.connection.HostRequiredError: BotoClientError: When using SigV4, you must specify a 'host' parameter.`

Do anybody have any idea how to set the host parameter?

Answer (score 0):

put this in your config/settings file:

```
AWS_S3_HOST = 's3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com'
```

Here 'eu-central-1' specifies Franfurt region. For regions other than Franfurt, refer the link http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-regions-availability-zones.html